# Graphical boot-up screen lost after upgrading the kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, boot, display-settings

I used the Ubuntu 10.10 alternate install CD to install Maverick to an encrypted partition on a USB stick. This worked perfectly, but after the first cycle of updates that took the kernel from 2.6.35-22 to 2.6.35-24 I no longer get the graphical boot screen that asks for my passphrase. Instead I get a similar looking one that uses ASCII art.

If I select the older 22 kernel from the bootloader, I still get the nice graphical screen.

What do I need to do to get the nicer boot-up interface with the newer 24 kernel?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Try installing grub2

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with kernel `24` and incompatibility with Nvidia graphics drivers. From what I can see it was fixed with the `28` update.